# The history is shared between my iTerm2 terminal tabs: how can I switch that off?

Tags: macos, command-line, iterm, zsh

I am using iTerm2 (with zsh), and for some reason the history is shared between the different tabs and windows that are open. In most of the cases for me, this is annoying, since I have tabs per specific task, and if I have to redo some commands, I just want to be able to go back (up) in history to retrieve the last action for *that* window/tab only.

I have no idea how to disable this shared history, I read somewhere that you can *enable* shared history in `zsh`, but afaik I have done no such thing.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Executing the following should do the trick (use `setopt` to reenable them):

```
unsetopt inc_append_history
unsetopt share_history
```

Comment: Do I add these to my `.zshrc`?

Comment: and with bash???

Comment: @nathanvda yep, you add this to `.zshrc`.

Comment: What about bash shell?

Comment: @Adi you can either add it to your `.bashrc` or your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I am getting `-bash: unsetopt: command not found`. Is it possible that this is something tmux related? Afaik I am not using tmux, but I am still experiencing the same problem as OP

Comment: The question and this answer are specific to `zsh`.  I don't think there is an equivalent fix for Bash.

Comment: @TabeaKischka : `unsetopt` is not a builtin bash command.  It does not make sense to execute zsh code in bash. You wouldn't run Perl code in Java either, would you?

Answer (score 0):

For me above mentioned commands didn't work.

I am using plain ZSH, not Oh-my-zsh.

Here's what worked for me (./zshrc):

```
export HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_sessions/history_$TERM_SESSION_ID" # use a different histfile per shell
setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY # new history lines are added to the file as soon as they are entered (not after terminal is closed)
if [ ! -e $HISTFILE ]; then cp "$HOME/.zsh_sessions/$(ls -Art $HOME/.zsh_sessions | tail -n 1)" "$HISTFILE"; fi # for new shells, initialize history with the history of the most recently used shell
```