# How to switch off sharing of history between iTerm2 tabs when setopt command not found

Tags: terminal, iterm, tmux

I am experiencing the same problem as in this question: [The history is shared between my iTerm2 terminal tabs: how can I switch that off?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75571/the-history-is-shared-between-my-iterm2-terminal-tabs-how-can-i-switch-that-off). As the user describes, my history is shared between different tabs and windows in iTerm2, which is very annoying.

I cannot use the solution suggested to the linked question, as I cannot use the `setopt` command:

```
-bash: setopt: command not found
```

I am using iTerm2 Build 3.0.12 on OS X El Capitan, 10.11.6 and GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15) and tmux 2.3.
When I start only tmux, I am also getting the following error message:

```
tmux
-bash: iterm2_preexec_invoke_cmd: command not found
```

Deleting my iTerm2 profile/User Settings and starting with a "fresh", non-customized iTerm2 didn't help.

Does one of you maybe have an idea what I could try?
Thanks!

**Edit**:

Here is the output of `shopt -p | grep histappend`:

```
$ shopt -p | grep histappend
shopt -u histappend
```

and `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND`

```
$ echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
history -a; history -c; history -r; date | xargs echo -n >>~/.bash_history_workingdir; echo -n ' - ' >>~/.bash_history_workingdir; pwd | xargs echo -n >>~/.bash_history_workingdir; echo -n ' - ' >>~/.bash_history_workingdir; tail -n 1 /Users/tabea/.bash_eternal_history >>~/.bash_history_workingdir; iterm2_preexec_invoke_cmd
```

My output for `$PROMPT_COMMAND` looks so long, since I changed the default behaviour of the history command, in order to keep an "eternal" bash history (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19533853/897521)). I never suspected that this could cause the weird shared-history-in-iTerm-behaviour, since I have had this in my `~/.bashrc` already before the problem started.

The relevant part of my `~/.bashrc` looks like this:

```
##########################################################
# Eternal bash history.
# ---------------------
# Undocumented feature which sets the size to "unlimited".
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457233/unlimited-bash-history
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T] "
# Change the file location because certain bash sessions truncate .bash_history file upon close.
# http://superuser.com/questions/575479/bash-history-truncated-to-500-lines-on-each-login
export HISTFILE=~/.bash_eternal_history
# Force prompt to write history after every command.
# http://superuser.com/questions/20900/bash-history-loss

export CUSTOM_HISTFILE="~/.bash_history_workingdir" #path of the new history file
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; date | xargs echo -n >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; echo -n ' - ' >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; pwd | xargs echo -n >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; echo -n ' - ' >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; tail -n 1 $HISTFILE >>$CUSTOM_HISTFILE; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: `setopt` is zsh-specific - the bash equivalent is `shopt`. Could you run `shopt -p | grep histappend` and report back what you see? Also, could you run `echo $PROMPT_COMMAND` and report that, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `history -a` part of `PROMPT_COMMAND` in your `.bashrc` - that's appending to the history file every time a prompt is displayed, whatever tab you're using. A quick fix would be to remove this, so that each tab's session only writes to `.bash_history` when the session ends (e.g. when the tab is closed).

I *like* this behaviour (immediate appends to `.bash_history`), and I suspect you may too! A better solution may be to maintain *separate* histories for each session/tab - one of the answers [to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56446/shell-deal-with-multiple-command-history-files) describes how to achieve that. You could retain immediate appends, but to separate files - one for each session. You would still be able to search your entire bash history with a command like `grep "foo" ~/.bash_hist*`. (I've not personally tried this: I use one history file for all sessions, since my normal workflow tends to be in one tab or through `screen`, and I archive my `/bash_history` periodically into a separate file, as described [in this article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/088) - which is well worth reading, even if it doesn't address your issue).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it! I haven't modified my `.bashrc` yet to to write into separate history files, as suggested as in the other posts, so I can't comment on how it is working. But it has solved my problems of shared histories.

Comment: sorry... what exactly was the solution here?