# Is it possible to have iTerm2 restore the session history?

Tags: iterm

Currently when re-launching iTerm2 I'll get my window setup back, but they all share a common history. I.e. whatever is in `~/.bash_history`. Can I get it to restore my sessions with the actual session history for each individual window instead?

Comment: Maybe the answers to this questions help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/75571/62251 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/261003/62251 ?